# Change Android widget size on upgrade

Tags: android, android-widget, widget

I have written a widget with size 74x74 in version 1. In version 2 I want to change the size to 148x74. I want this to happen during upgrade, is this possible? or does the user have to remove and add the widget again?

Answer (score 0):

User will have to remove and install widget again.  Actually, widget placed on home screen is
detached from your application - it just sends update events to it and home screen reacts on them.  And possible updates are pretty limited.